# Is pennylane free?

Tags: quantum-gate, ibm-q-experience, pennylane

I was going through the basics of pennylane. I am able to understand that it is used for quantum neural networks. I am not sure whether it is using paid cloud computer or simulator of xandu or ibmq? Do I need to create some account for using it? Please guide whether it is paid or free?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, Pennylane is "free". It is open-source software developed under the Apache 2.0 License. Creating circuits and running local simulations in Pennylane does not require an account. However, submitting your quantum programs to be executed on photonic hardware or to be run on a cloud simulator via the Xanadu Cloud does require an account. See [Strawberry Fields](https://strawberryfields.readthedocs.io/en/stable/introduction/photonic_hardware.html). Pennylane and IBMQ are two separate entities, though Pennylane does offer integration with Qiskit. See [Pennylane-Qiskit plugin](https://pennylaneqiskit.readthedocs.io/en/latest/).

Comment: Thank you @ryanhill1